# How to retrieve an entity from the datastore using its unique key id in createQuery

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

Using 'gcloud' for node.js I am trying retrieve an entity from the datastore using the unique key id that the datastore allocated to it during the creation.

I have tried lots of different createQuery setups and none of them work.

```
const kind = 'campaign';

var q = ds.createQuery([kind])
.filter('id', '=', 5672749318012928);

var q = ds.createQuery([kind])
.filter('id', 5672749318012928);

var q = ds.createQuery([kind])
.filter('key', '=', 5672749318012928);

var q = ds.createQuery([kind])
.filter('__key__ =', ['campaign', 5672749318012928]);

var q = ds.createQuery([kind])
.filter('__key__', '=', ['campaign', 5672749318012928]);
```

I have tested the query using one of its properties and it worked fine, returning a result:

```
const kind = 'campaign';

var q = ds.createQuery([kind])
       .filter('campaign_id', '=', 1286372673);
```

Am I missing something, can you actually filter based on its unique key?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
var q = ds.createQuery([kind])
    .filter('__key__', '=', ds.key(['campaign', 5672749318012928]));
```

However, if you are fetching a single entity by its key, the `lookup` command is more efficient:

```
var k = ds.key(['campaign', 5672749318012928])
ds.get(k, function (err, entity) {
    ...      
  }
});
```

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries